# Exchanging data between xaml and aspx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, silverlight, interaction

I have a solution with MVC web application, WCF web service and Silverlight. MVC starts Silverlight and Silverlight gets the parameters using web service. Now I have to pass a variable from Silverlight to MVC (not with get/post). How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd148642.aspx) for information about accessing th HTML DOM from Silverlight. And see [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/dotnet/silverlight/2.0/htmlbridge.html) to see  how to access JavaScript from Silverlight.